# Sort Object with Object using ng-repeat in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

My question is:
I want to sort an Object whose children are Object using ng-repeat.

```
facets = {
    'tm_mailbox': {buckets: [{key:'budlion', doc_count:1037}]},
       'tm_user': {buckets: [{key:'karl', doc_count:10}, {key:'kael2', doc_count:111}] },
    'tm_message': {buckets: [{key:'sylvia', doc_count:298}] }};

facets_ordered_keys = ['tm_user', 'tm_message', 'tm_mailbox']
```

The object will be sorted A-Z by default. I want to order the object.

I used two **ng-repeat**, the first loop will read sorted keys and second loop will read value by the key, such as the loop in pseudo code:

```
for k in facets_ordered_keys:
    print k
    for v in facets[k]:
       print v
```

**But I cannot read facets[k] in the 2nd ng-repeat.**

Here is code in angular js:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-init="facets =
    {'tm_mailbox': {buckets: [{key:'budlion', doc_count:1037}]},
    'tm_user': {buckets: [{key:'karl', doc_count:10}, {key:'kael2', doc_count:111}] },
    'tm_message': {buckets: [{key:'sylvia', doc_count:298}] }};
    facets_ordered_keys = ['tm_user', 'tm_message', 'tm_mailbox']
">
    <div ng-repeat=" k in facets_ordered_keys ">
      <p>k is: {{k}}</p>
      <p>In facets values is:{{facets[k]}}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
   
   <!-- why i cannot read facets[k]? -->  
    <div ng-repeat=" k in facets_ordered_keys ">
      <dt>{{k}}</dt>
      <dl ng-repeat="v in facets[k]">
        <dd ng-repeat="bucket in v.buckets">
          <label>{{bucket.key}}</label>
          <span>{{bucket.doc_count}}</span>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-init="facets =
    {'tm_mailbox': {buckets: [{key:'budlion', doc_count:1037}]},
    'tm_user': {buckets: [{key:'karl', doc_count:10}, {key:'kael2', doc_count:111}] },
    'tm_message': {buckets: [{key:'sylvia', doc_count:298}] }};
    facets_ordered_keys = ['tm_user', 'tm_message', 'tm_mailbox']
">
    <div ng-repeat=" k in facets_ordered_keys ">
      <p>k is: {{k}}</p>
      <p>In facets values is:{{facets[k]}}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
   
   <!-- why i cannot read facets[k]? -->  
    <div ng-repeat=" k in facets_ordered_keys ">
      <dt>{{k}}</dt>
      <dl ng-repeat="v in facets[k]">  
        <dd ng-repeat="bucket in v">  
          <label>{{bucket.key}}</label>
          <span>{{bucket.doc_count}}</span>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think he doesn't need the extra `ng-repeat` on `facets[k]`, since he just cares about the `buckets` property on the object. So there just should be one nested loop of `<dd ng-repeat="bucket in facets[k].buckets">`

Comment: Yes. unless he wants a "<dl />" tag  wrapped around "<dd/>" tags.